# Using YAML::store, do updated yml files in production get wiped out on deployment of the updated app?

Tags: ruby

I am using the YAML::store to store a list of strings and I didn't want to use the database to limit the need for SQL queries. The strings can be added or updated by admin users. I was wondering if the .yml file will be updated in production and if the data will be wiped out when I deploy an updated version of the app to production.

Answer (score 1):

> *I am using the rails YAML::store...*

[YAML::Store](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML/Store.html) is not part of Rails, but a regular Ruby standard library.

> *I was wondering if the .yml file will be updated in production and if the data will be wiped out when I deploy an updated version of the app to production.*

YAML::Store just writes to a file of your choice. What happens to that file depends entirely on your deployment process and production environment. If you're running your own server or on a single virtual machine it's likely safe. If it's a cloud service like [Heroku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku), any files are likely not safe.

> *I didn't want to use the database to limit the need for SQL queries.*

This is likely a poor trade off. YAML::Store has to load and parse the entire file every time its read. Any changes mean rewriting the entire file. As the file gets larger this will get worse and worse.

Worse, using local files limits you to a single instance of your program. This means you cannot scale up by adding another production instance.

In contrast, simple database queries are extremely fast and robust. There's no concern about whether a local file will be wiped out. Any number of instances can connect to the database. And databases can also be scaled to have multiple instances.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for correcting me. This clarifies a lot for me.